# Unable to locate xml file using ClassPathResource in Spring Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, classpath, filenotfoundexception

I'm migrating the project from xml based configuration to java based configuration.

I was able to define all the beans successfully except one.
**The XMLViewResolver**
We are using JasperReports, so all the jrxml files are defined in the reports.xml
From my classpath, I'm not able to locate the xml file.

I have tried only by adding the **reports.xml** inside the ClassPathResource, but still, I  get an error during the project building time.

```
@Bean 
public ViewResolver xmlViewResolver() {
        logger.info("xmlViewResolver");
        XmlViewResolver bean = new XmlViewResolver();
        bean.setOrder(10);
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/reports.xml"));
        return bean;
    }
```

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/reports.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 47 more
```

Old xml code:

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="order" value="0" />
        <beans:property name="location"
            value="/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/reports.xml" />
</beans:bean>
```

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: It is not on the _class path_ (where the .class files are too), but an actual file on the site in the WEB_INF directory.

Comment: Place the reports.xml somewhere under src/main/resources, and use the path from there as classpath resource

Comment: @JoopEggen, Thanks for responding. Even with the "spring/appServlet/reports.xml" it shows the same error

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/appServlet/reports.xml]

Comment: Thanks. Once I moved to reports.xml to src/main/resources and changed the location to   bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("reports.xml"));, its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the reports.xml to src/main/resources and changed the location as follows

```
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("reports.xml"));
```

Now the project is able to read and detect the .xml file

[image]